# Jenkins Git Publisher, multiple repos and Multiple SCM

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

We have multiple Git repositories, all required for a single build so we have to use MultiSCM to get source.

I'm hooking it up to  Git Publisher, to push a tag after each build, and it works nicely on a test against a single repo, but I can't get it to play nice with MultiSCM. Is it possible?

Comment: IMHO you are using it wrong and should change your setup: If it's one thing, use one repo. If there are multiple elements (libraries,...) use proper dependency management with Maven or whatever the right tool for your language is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is the plugin doesn't support multiple repos (yet).  It's much easier to add a final job step that cds into each repo and runs git tag; git push --tags.

Comment: I store a service account key on the slave (needed for other reasons).

Comment: Has there been any update to this?  Or is it still just easier to run the git commands in a script?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you won't be able to publish tags to multiple Git repositories until this bug is fixed: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13779.  But don't hold your breath.  Note that the bug is nearly 4 years old already.